# не могу установить библиотеку (python 3.10)

Tags: python

C:\Users\User\Desktop\bot003\forcfg\cmd\cfgg>pip install -r requirements.txt
Usage: **main**.py [options]

ERROR: Invalid requirement: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
**main**.py: error: no such option: -m

Comment: Какое содержимое файла requirements.txt?